# How to share application settings between app services in Azure?

Tags: azure, web-config, app-config, octopus-deploy, appsettings

I have several App Services in Azure: development, test, and production. I would like to share some application settings between them like variable sets in [Octopus](https://octopus.com/).

Let's say I have a key A which should be same in all App Services. I would like to set its value in one place but seems that I have to configure it to each App Service. When A is changed, I have to change it to everywhere instead of having one common place to change it. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No built-in way, app settings are part of the App Service resource.

You will need to put the settings in a common database or file.
Azure Key Vault can be used for sensitive settings and table storage/blob storage works well for other settings. Azure SQL is also an option.

Your app will then need to load these settings at startup.

This is also a documented cloud design pattern: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/external-configuration-store